# Regex: .exec() function not returning expected output

Tags: javascript, regex

This doesn't return what I, or regex101, expects:

```
var myString = "Accel World|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/accel-worldAh! My Goddess|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/ah-my-goddess";
var reg = /[^|]*/g;
var regResponse = reg.exec(myString);
console.log(regResponse);
```

according to regex101, this should match everything except '|' and return it yet it only matches the first string, Accel World, as opposed to everything but '|'.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What you've asked it to match is zero-or-more **consecutive** characters that are not `|`. Why not just use `myString.split('|')` to get an array of strings separated by `|`?

Comment: Interesting, any clue why regex101 returns everything instead of just consecutive? That seems odd because it is highly recommended. The .split might work, thanks for the idea.

Comment: Probably because it doesn't use `exec` which behaves differently to how you expect it to. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches

Comment: regex101 probably uses something more like `myString.match(reg)`

Comment: The sad thing is I read the documentation and somehow completely misinterpreted what they were saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop `.exec()` to retrieve all matches. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) says

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec()
>   method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.

```
var reg = /[^|]+/g;
while(regResponse = reg.exec(myString)) {
    console.log(regResponse);
}
```

Comment: While `exec` is a valid way to approach this, `match` is more convenient in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Exec will only return one result at a time (*subsequent calls will return the rest, but you also need to use the `+` instead of `*`*)

You could use the `myString.match(reg)` htough to get all results in one go.

```
var myString = "Accel World|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/accel-worldAh! My Goddess|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/ah-my-goddess";
var reg = /[^|]+/g;
var regResponse = myString.match(reg);
console.log(regResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a "+" instead of the "*"

So,

```
var reg = /[^|]+/g;
```

Comment: Doesn't change what exec() returns.

Comment: @ActionON it does if you run `exec` more than once